# How to set the delivery time for new messages in mailbox?

Tags: python

I am trying to set the date for newly created Maildir messages.
However the documented method 'set_date' does not seem to work.

```
msg = mailbox.MaildirMessage()
sec = 1435512303.0
origin = "Sender"

# doesn't seem to work
msg.set_unixfrom('{0} {1}'.format(origin, sec))

# doesn't seem to work either
msg.set_date(sec)
```

What am I over looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the send time you have to manipulate the header.

```
msg.__setitem__('Date',
                time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",
                              entry_time))
```